# MongoDB -PHP data update

Tags: php, forms, mongodb, php-mongodb

For save data from form to MongoDB database i'm using this code.

```
if (isset($_POST))
{   
    $m = new MongoClient();   
    $db = $m->abst;
    $collection = $db->users;
    print_r($_POST);    
    if($collection->find(array('user_id' => $pid)))
    {
        $collection->update(array('user_id'=>$pid),$_POST);
    }
    else
    { 
        $document = array_merge(array('user_id'=>$pid),$_POST);
        $collection->insert($document);   
    }  
}
```

How can check user id exist in collection? and if user id exist in collection, data will update. Otherwise new entry saved to collection. where is the mistake?

Answer (score 0):

Try this  - maybe it will work for you.

In MongoDB if a record does not exist for given query and if upsert is `true` then mongodb adds the record as a new record.

```
$query['user_id'] = $pid;
$object['$set'] = $_POST;
$options = array('w' => true, 'upsert' => true);
$collection->update($query, $object, $options);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if($collection->find(array('user_id' => $pid))->count() == 1)
    {
        $collection->update(array('user_id'=>$pid),$_POST);
    }
```